# im creating a program that will automatically search when the textbox change and view it on datagrid but i have this error

Tags: ms-access-2010, vb.net-2010

'c:\users\gole\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WindowsApplication15\bin\Debug\Application.StartupPath & \data.accdb' is not a valid path. Make sure that the path name is specified

heres my code:

System.Data.OleDb
Public Class Form1
    Dim con As New OleDbConnection

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= Application.StartupPath & data.accdb"
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    con.Open()

    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    ds.Tables.Add(dt)
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter

    da = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from student where ID like '%" & TextBox1.Text & "%'", con)
    da.Fill(dt)

    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt.DefaultView

    con.Close()

End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" _
       & "Data Source= Application.StartupPath & data.accdb"
```

to

```
con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" _
       & Application.StartupPath & "\data.accdb"
```

Comment: Is the error message (...is not a valid path...) still the same?